# Post data to PHP with AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, json

Im trying to send data to PHP with AJAX. I already tryed sending it with JSON, with $.post and $.ajax, but all it does - it returns **Notice: Undefined index: id in C:\xampp\htdocs\PHP Test\db\editform.php on line 7**

What am I doing wrong?

**HTML**

```
<form action="" method="post" class="usereditform">
  <input type="hidden" name="id" value="'.$db_row['id'].'">
  <input type="hidden" name="key" value="'.$_SESSION['security_key'].'">
</form>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).on('click', '.edit_user', function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  var form = $(this).parent().find('form.usereditform');
  var post_url = 'db/editform.php';
  var post_data = form.serialize();

  $.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: post_url,
    data:post_data,
    success: function () {
      $('.edit_user_form_placeholder').load('db/editform.php');
      $('.edit_user_popup').fadeIn();
    }
  });
});
```

**PHP - editform.php**

```
$id = $_POST['id'];
echo $id;
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="popup edit_user_popup" style="display:none;">
  <div class="popup_container">
    <div class="edit_user_form_placeholder"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `post_data` in your JS is most likely not what you expect it to be

Comment: can you print your post array and post the output     print_r($_POST);

Comment: fi you have an error in line 7 of editform.php it would be helpful for give us more than 2 lines of the file

Comment: Are you using a web server? AJAX expects a web server.

Comment: it looks like `id=17&key=afkjhajf9q27928347` @kingkero

Comment: Undefined index means that you are likely to read some data that is not there. Check if you receive your formdata and that you process it correctly.

Comment: @Horaland there is just commented out code, everything but these two lines is commented out :)

Comment: @JayBlanchard I work on local server. AJAX works perfectly with all other forms i have on this page.

Comment: add print_r($_POST); and see what you are actiually getting.

Comment: @Horaland it returns an empty array

Comment: Have you watched the request / response in your browser's console?

Comment: Firebug returns `Array ([id] => 17 [key] => 8225afc8d4a5f129a2038bf0c1cbfb74)` as a response for editform.php

Comment: @kingkero Ok, I think i gotta take some rest, after a long work day lol That  was the issue, thank you a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are actually sending two requests:

```
  //first request with proper settings
  $.ajax({
    ...
    success: function () {
      //second request without any posted data
      $('.edit_user_form_placeholder').load('db/editform.php');
      ...
    }
  });
```

Instead, use the data that you get returned by the request itself. Using the `$.post` method this could be done the following way

```
$.post(post_url, post_data, function(result) {
                                  // ^- this is the data that gets returned by the request
    $('.edit_user_form_placeholder').html(result);
    $('.edit_user_popup').fadeIn();
});
```

Comment: Yup, thats exactly how i corrected it :) Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This is the way I'm currently communicating to PHP via ajax. I find it the easiest way, and can be done without forms.

**jQuery**

```
 var dataString = 'key1='+ value1 + '&key2='+ value2; //values you want to send
    $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "db/editform.php",
            data: dataString,
            cache: false,
            success: function(result){
            //success text
            }
     });
```

**PHP - editform.php**

And recieve like so.

```
$rowid = $_POST['key1'];
$securitykey = $_POST['key1'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with parsing the data you are posting into a JSON object?

```
var post_data = JSON.stringify(form.serializeArray());
```

The data you are passing to your ajax call are not formatted in a JSON object.

Comment: yeah, i tryed it alreay, but its just another way of doing it :) i already fixed it, the issue was that i was sending two requests